# Head-up display in multi-document interface

Tags: hud

I work on a complex enterprise web application that allows users to manage various entities of a traffic system. To fasten the workflow for advanced users, I consider using the head-up display (HUD UI) in similar way how is done in Ubuntu.

[image: Ubuntu HUD]

I have come across a "scope" problem: some HUD commands are global (`open traffic history`), while some other are related to a certain entity (`switch device KS1803`).

So, I have the following questions:

- Do you have any experience with HUD UI? Would you recommend it in this case?
- How would you solve the handling of global and context commands? Does it make sense to combine them in a global search box, e.g. with some extra intelligence for the auto-complete mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you should use it or not depends heavily on the scope of your application. Since you said it's a complex application and you have advanced users, something like the HUD would probably help the UX.

However, there are some things to watch our for:

- The HUD should be really good at understanding queries, otherwise the user will have to type multiple times to find what they want.
- It shouldn't replace the other ways of accessing that functionality. For example, the Ubuntu HUD lets you search an application's menus, but the original menus are still there.
- If you can survey your audience and see what they prefer, you'll have a better idea of whether the HUD is a good fit for your application.